# Juggling algorithm of string rotation

Tags: algorithm

There are several ways to deal with **string rotation**.
"Programming Pearls" talks about **string rotation** in deep, with three linear algorithms.(click [here](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/s02b.pdf) to check it)

The first one is called "Juggling algorithm", which I spent a lot time to study it, but I still can't understand the role that **Great Common Divisor** plays in it. Can anybody explain it in detail ?

Comment: Currently your question is greatly dependent on that link, which isn't all that appropriate according to [so] guidelines. Could you extract the applicable algorithm from the link and put it in the question?

Comment: You can go through the algorithm with pencil and paper. In the example, the array length `n` and the distance `d` are co-prime, the cgd is 1. You swap the elements in the order (0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5) - all elements have been visited. If your `d` is 4, the gcd is 4, too, and you swap only (0, 4) in the first cycle and you have to do that cycle again with offsets of 1, 2 and 3. In short: There are two nested loops. The product of the loop lengths must be your `n` and the inner loop length depends on the divisibility of `n` by `d`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Juggling Algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221279/juggling-algorithm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You rotate the elements by moving them in steps of `d`. This process loops back after a certain number of moves, so that you need to apply `m` cycles of length `l=n/m` in total.

`l` is the first value that solves the equation `l.d = 0 (mod n)`, so that `m` is precisely `gcd(n, d)`.

```
Example 1: for n=12, d=3, 3 cycles of length 4:
 0  3  6  9
 1  4  7 10
 2  5  8 11

Example 2: for n=12, d=10, 2 cycles of length 6:
 0 10 8 6 4 2
 1 11 9 7 5 3
```

Comment: There are some mathematics (group theory) that this is related to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574501/raising-a-cycle-to-a-power-cycle-decomposition  ... every rotation of an array/string by d steps can be viewed as taking the d-th power of the permutation `(1 2 ... n)`. A theorem that states that the dth power of this permutation can be decomposed into gcd(d, n) disjoint cycles.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your explanation! However, it was not very intuitive to me that you can jump to the conclusion

> m=gcd(n,d)

, so I just want to share my reasoning here:

Since you want to find the smallest value such that 
`((n/m)*d)%n == 0`, it means u want to find the biggest `m` that can satisfy this requirement. Starting from `m = n`, u can try it one by one and find out that when `m=gcd(n,d)` the equation is fulfilled. This is because:  `(n/m)*d = (n/m)*((d/m)*m) = n*(d/m)`. We need to ensure that `d/m` as well as `n/m` are both valid integers, and for the maximum such `m`, it must be the case that `m=gcd(n,d)`.

Comment: Why "you want to find the smallest value such that ((n/m)*d)%n == 0"?