# Juggling algorithm regarding Right Array rotation

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Recently I learnt about the array rotation in linear time using Juggling algorithm. Here is the snippet regarding the left rotation of the array.

```
void ArrayRotate (int A[], int n, int k)
{
  int d=-1,i,temp,j;
  for(i=0;i<gcd(n,k);i++)
  {
    j=i;
    temp=A[i];
    while(1)
    {
      d=(j+k)%n;
      if(d==i)
        break;
      A[j]=A[d];
      j=d;
    }
    A[j]=temp;
  }
}
```

but now I am stuck as how to use this Juggling algorithm to rotate the array in the Right Direction.

```
1,2,3,4,5  (given array) 
5,1,2,3,4   (after 1 right rotation)
```

(I had solved this question using the brute force method and reversal method.)

Comment: Please tag only one language unless the question is about interoperation of the two or differences between them

Comment: `for(i=n-1;i<gcd(n,k);i--)` -- Off topic, but you are computing `gcd(n,k)` on each iteration of your loop.  Simply calculate it once, store it in a variable, and use that variable in the `for` loop.

Comment: `for(i=n-1;i<gcd(n,k);i--)` is going to stop immediately, unless `n < k` and `n` is a prime factor of `k`, surely ?

Comment: @ChrisHall sir, I had corrected the code.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I had removed duplicate tags

Answer (score 1):

1. As already mentioned, you should use std::rotate if you are allowed to.
2. Your implementation has a bug. Here is a fixed implementation.

```
void ArrayRotate(int A[], int n, int k) {
    int d = -1, i, temp, j;
    int g = gcd(n, k);
    for (i = 0; i < g; ++i) {
        j = i;
        temp = A[i];
        while (true) {
            d = (j + k) % n;
            if (d == i) {
                break;
            }
            A[j] = A[d];
            j = d;
        }
        A[j] = temp;
    }
 }
```

Also note that I took out gcd calculation out of loop condition. It does not technically affect complexity, but it's enough to compute the gcd only once.

To rotate the array `k` times to the right, just rotate it `n - k` times to the left.

```
void ArrayRotateRight(int A[], int n, int k) {
    ArrayRotate(A, n, n - k);
}
```

Or change the 8th line to be `d = (j - k + n) % n;`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're doing this as an intellectual exercise, or for production code, but for production code use the STL `rotate` algorithm:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

void display(int* a, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        cout << a[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    const int len = 5;

    int arr[] =  { 1,2,3,4,5 };

    display(arr, len);

    rotate(arr, arr + 1, arr + len); // arr + x means left by x

    display(arr, len);

    rotate(arr, arr + len - 1, arr + len); // arr + len - x means right by x 

    display(arr, len);
}
```

Comment: i solved this question using stl only. but found a cool way here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321216/rotating-an-array-using-juggling-algorithm and just was wondering how to implement the other way.