# Time complexity of Juggling Algorithm (array rotation)

Tags: arrays, time-complexity

I recently learnt about how the Juggling algorithm rotates an array in linear time

```html
/*Function to left rotate arr[] of siz n by d*/
void leftRotate(int arr[], int d, int n)
{
  int i, j, k, temp;
  for (i = 0; i < gcd(d, n); i++)
  {
    /* move i-th values of blocks */
    temp = arr[i];
    j = i;
    while(1)
    {
      k = j + d;
      if (k >= n)
        k = k - n;
      if (k == i)
        break;
      arr[j] = arr[k];
      j = k;
    }
    arr[j] = temp;
  }
}
```

How time complexity is linear???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Juggling Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221279/juggling-algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

- For loop in the function `leftRotate(int arr[], int d, int n)` make
  exactly `gcd(d, n)` iterations.
- [Time complexity of gcd(d,n)](https://codility.com/media/train/10-Gcd.pdf) function is `O(log(d)+log(n))`.
- Inside the while loop it takes all the cells arr[k] which fulfill `k
  % gcd(d, n) == i` and swaps them.
- There are exactly `n / gcd(d, n)` cells and it is the number of swaps
  this function will make in one iteration of the loop.
- Therefore the whole asymptotic time complexity of the function is
  going to be

  `O(gcd(d, n) * n / gcd(d, n))`
- which is `O(n)` "linear".